# Outlook PST File Parsing in Python

Tags: python, outlook, pst

How can I parse and read an outlook pst file in Python?

Comment: I wasted several days finding a reliable way to do that, so the initial question was definitively a good question!
I'd like the item reopened so that I can post the solution I found eventually, using the win32com.client library, available in standard Python distributions for Windows.

Comment: @Jean-FrançoisLarvoire could you point to a resource or some documentation for the solution you found?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have only ever poked at libpst docs, but it looks like the libpst-python package might work for you: [libpst-python](http://www.five-ten-sg.com/libpst/packages/centos4/)

Answer (score 17):

[pypff](https://github.com/libyal/libpff)  is a python wrapper for the C library libpff that allows you to access email and the directory structure of Pst files within python.

Do a make of the library with the specified command to install the python bindings.  Then you should be able to open up the python console and browse through Pst files.

```
import pypff

pst = pypff.file()
pst.open("MyPst.pst")
pst.close()
```

There are more examples on the libraries website.  However, I found that there wasn't enough functionality in the library yet.  For instance, you can read emails and the directories, but there isn't anything for attachments yet.

Comment: When I imported this module into my python script, it said it didn't exist. I'm using python 2.7

Comment: How did you install it?

Comment: Hi I am currently working on pypff as well, however having some trouble installing it and getting around with using it with python on a Window's machine. Do you think you can elaborate with the installation and such?

Comment: install it using `pip install libpff-python`.

Comment: Is there a way to open password-protected PSTs with `pypff`?