# Convert pst file to msg files

Tags: python, msg, pst

I am trying to write a program that will take msg files and extract data fields from the msg files such as to, cc, bcc, subject, date/time sent etc. Using the Python library extract_msg I have successfully done this.

What I now need to do is add the functionality to **extract individual emails from PST files at bulk into individual MSG files**.

I've looked around for a python library that will easily achieve this but I am struggling to find anything. Does anyone have any good suggestions on how I might do this?

Comment: https://docs.aspose.com/email/pythonnet/working-with-messages-in-a-pst-file/ Hope this helps

Comment: Check out the answers to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3197388/9705687) which suggest a couple of libraries, including one that @ArunbhYashaswi suggested.

Answer (score 0):

What I now need to do is add the functionality to extract individual emails from PST files at bulk into individual MSG files.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).